# Call a javascript function after Single time every 7 days

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on node.js. I created a function I want to call it 1 time after every 7 days. I am able to call it after 7 days but I want to call this after every 7 days.

Comment: Look `setInterval` function

Comment: You can also take a look at creating cron jobs, like [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this amazing library
https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule